# Area from polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, curves

Find the area bounded by the curve $r=2a\cos(3x)$ which is outside of the circle $r=a$, $a>0$.

I have problem finding the range for the angle.
I think $\cos(3x)\ge0$ and $2a\cos(3x)\ge a$ and in this way we can find the range for $x$ and then apply the formula for the area?
Am I right? Please help!

Comment: draw by hand both curves and see what happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: you only need the area outside of the circle, then you need to find all the intervals of $x\in[0,2\pi)$ where $|2a\cos(3x)|\ge a$ and the function is injective (that is, the same part of the curve is not plotted twice in the previously mentioned range of $x$).

Because the area is the same in these intersections then it would be enough to count how many times these areas occur, and multiply this number by the area of one of these intersections.

> Graphing the function $f(\theta):=2a\cos(3\theta)(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$, or from a brief analysis, we can see that it have 3 "petals", thus we only need to find the area between one of these petals and the circle (outside the circle), what is defined by $$A(P)=\frac12\int_{-\pi/6}^{\pi/6} (4a^2\cos^2(3\theta)-a^2)\,\mathrm d\theta=\frac{a^2}3\int_0^{\pi/2}(4\cos^2(\alpha)-1)\,\mathrm d\alpha=a^2\frac{\pi}6$$ Thus the total area is $a^2\pi/2$.

Comment: I think $2acos(3x)$ must be positive because $r>=0$ Am I wrong?

Comment: $2a\cos(3x)\ge a$ leads me to $x \in [0,\pi/9] U [5\pi/9,2\pi/3]$

Comment: yes, you are wrong. It can be negative also. If it is negative then the piece of curve is plotted in the opposite direction. You will get a good intuition about how the curve looks like plotting curves like $g(t):=\cos(n x)(\cos t,\sin t)$, for some $n\in\Bbb N$. These curves have a shape like flowers.

Comment: Please can you give a complete solution. It is a big mess for me

Comment: I made it. Thanks!